# php code is not working?

Tags: php, html

I am fresher and learning php from youtube tutorials. But in tutorials same php code is working without any error while on my system it is showing something which is shown in the picture. Please help!!

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user_input'])&&!empty($_POST['user_input']))
{
    $string = $_POST['user_input'];
    echo $string;
}
?>
<hr>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name="user_input" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $user_input; ?></textarea>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: `$user_input` is never defined

Comment: -1 for bad headline... "php code is not working?" is a really vague description of your issue.

Comment: in the future please just post the error message text rather than a screen shot.

Comment: The video you've chosen to watch was made by someone with `register_globals` turned on. This person cannot teach you how to program PHP well because they're an awful programmer who will undoubtedly go on to teach you how to build nice SQL injection vulnerabilities into your code. Run away fast.

Answer (score 3):

You never defined `$user_input` when you called for it here: `<?php echo $user_input; ?>`.

I believe you'd want this as your code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user_input'])&&!empty($_POST['user_input']))
{
    $string = $_POST['user_input'];
    echo $string;
}
?>
<hr>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name="user_input" rows="10" cols="30"><?php if(isset($string)) echo $string; ?></textarea>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: It would probably be nicer to rewrite it to assign the variable `$user_input`instead of `$string` -- it's pretty common to give variables the same as the POST key.

Comment: i would be inclined towards `else $string='';` then you don't need `isset` again

Answer (score 0):

Just change the veritable name in textarea tag because you are not define `$user_input;` and place a condition if isset

> echo $user_input;

to

> echo ($string)?'$string':'';